Storing passwords with password hashed together with username
When reading about password storage, I usually encounter schemes that store username in plain text and a hash of its related password, so that during a login attempt the entered password is hashed and compared against the hash stored in the user database. This would imply that users with the same password have identical hashes, too.
The obvious weakness is that when the database is leaked, an attacker can try hashing trillions of likely passwords and see if any match some of the hashes from the database. If multiple users use the same password, then a successful hit reveals access to many accounts.
My question is this - why does the database not store a hash of (username+password) instead of hash of the password alone? This would make the login process similarly straightforward (instead of comparing the hash of password only, you would compare the hash of username and password concatenated as a string together. Usernames can be stored in plaintext like before).
It seems to me that this would greatly frustrate any efforts to breach the passwords in a brute-force hash search - instead of attacking the whole database at the same time, the attacker would need to try hashes against each username individually, which would decrease the overall yield of correct hashes, as now users with the same passwords would not be breached all at once.
I do not have expert knowledge of the storage systems beyond the superficial level described above, so maybe this is irrelevant or addressed in other ways, so feel free to correct any of my misconceptions.
Asking a general question

Have a look here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords. Basically, you salt the passwords in addition to hashing, so that same passwords does NOT results in same hash. This is a widely known way to securely store them.

@Alejandro is right. The added salt value prevents that same passwords produce the same hash-value. Another benefit of the salt is that attackers can not use already calculated hash-values to determine the password. The idea you had with the username is pretty similar to salt :-).

@Alejandro Thx. The post specifically addresses using usernames as salt, and while it is listed under bad practices, the only apparent weakness would be that it would make it somewhat worthwhile cracking or preparing rainbow tables for commonly used usernames like "admin" or "joe". This would only work on sites that use the same hashing scheme though, with no additional salt like site name for example. Another concern was with password changes that would lead to "salt reuse" with different password for the same user, although I can't really see much of a benefit to the attacker here.

@TondoPX Sharing hashing schemes is pretty common, as there aren't too many of them (and even fewer that are actually good). Using usernames as salt makes them easy to build rainbow tables for the common usernames, as they're inherently public, so a password change is more likely to be contained within the same table that defeated the first password. Adding a site name as salt is also of dubious efficiency, as you can also predict the salt and precalculate worthy targets in advance (although it effectively defeats cross-site rainbow tables). Having a completely random salt prevents all those.

@TondoPX Generating a random (salt) value is not difficult and because of the mentioned predictability issue there is no benefit in using user- or site-names.

If the salt is the same for each password in the database, then you can build one single rainbow table to get all passwords in one go. If the salt is unique for each password, you would have to build a table per password, which doesn't make sense because brute forcing is faster then. If interested, have a look at my tutorial about safely storing passwords.

Yes username is stored in database as a planetext but password in hash but do any thing when database get compromised by attackers then they collect a hashed password and username in palnetext . They may unhash a password and username is alreay in a palne text they convert hash to planetext.
